# How to find an XPath query to Element/Element without namespaces (XmlSerializer, fragment)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xpath

Assume this simple XML fragment in which there may or may not be the xml declaration and has exactly one `NodeElement` as a root node, followed by exactly one other `NodeElement`, which may contain an assortment of various number of different kinds of elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<NodeElement xmlns="xyz">
    <NodeElement xmlns="">
        <SomeElement></SomeElement>
    </NodeElement>
</NodeElement>
```

How could I go about selecting the inner `NodeElement` and its contents without the namespace? For instance, `"//*[local-name()='NodeElement/NodeElement[1]']"` (and other variations I've tried) doesn't seem to yield results.

As for in general the thing that I'm really trying to accomplish is to [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) a fragment of a larger XML document contained in a [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Something like the following

```
 var doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(@"trickynodefile.xml")); //ReadAllText to avoid Unicode trouble.
 var n = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='NodeElement/NodeElement[1]']");
 using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(n.OuterXml)))
 {
    var obj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NodeElementNodeElement)).Deserialize(reader);
```

I believe I'm missing just the right XPath expression, which seem to be rather elusive. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*/*
```

It selects children of the root node.

Or

```
/*/*[local-name() = 'NodeElement']
```

It selects children with `local-name() = 'NodeElement'` of the root node.

Anyway in your case both expressions select `<NodeElement xmlns="">`.

Answer (score 0):

walk the tree

```
foreach(XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.childnodes[0].childnodes)
{
    // do something with node
}
```

hideously fragile of course might want to check for nulls here and there.